# Read Text File And Plot It By Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, text

I have a Text file that contain such as this below data :

```
 E11E25E0E0E0E16E20E4E0E7E ........... etc.
```

And I want to read this file and plot its data .

How can I do that ?

Hint :

I think I must do these below steps :

1. Read the Text file Data by using ( `fopen` or `dlmread` or `fileread` ) , May be named this Data as ( `R` ) .
2. Remove the Char ( `E` ) from the Data ( `R` ) , May be renamed this Data as ( `RR` ) .
3. Then, the calculated Data ( `RR` ) be `[ 11 25 0 0 0 16 20 4 0 7 . . . . . ]` .
4. Then , determine the X-axis as follow : `t = 0 : length ( RR )-1;`
5. Finally, plot this data as follow : `plot(t,RR)`

Answer (score 2):

What you just need to do is properly tokenize your string (once you read it from your file).

Let `str_` be your string (`str_ = fileread(filename)`)

```
 >> str_ = 'E11E25E0E0E0E16E20E4E0E7E '
```

then

```
 nums = strread(str_,'E%d')    % # proper token structure has to be prescribed


 nums =

    11
    25
     0                                                                                                                                                                                          
     0                                                                                                                                                                                          
     0                                                                                                                                                                                          
    16                                                                                                                                                                                          
    20
     4
     0
     7
```

the plotting can be done via `plot`, there's no actual need to explicitly define the time axis.

```
  plot(nums)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir Acorbe ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of Acorbe's answer which also works in case you have multiple strings in a cell-string:

```
>> strs = {
       'E11E25E0E0E0E16E20E4E0E7E '
       'E11E28E0E0E0E16E20E4E0E7E ' };
>> 
>> %// greater flexibility:
>>
>> nrs = cellfun(@str2double, regexp(strs,'\d*','match'), 'UniformOutput',false);
>> nrs = cat(1, nrs{:})
ans =
    11    25     0     0     0    16    20     4     0     7
    11    28     0     0     0    16    20     4     0     7

>> %// greater speed: 
>> 
>> C = cellfun(@(x)strread(x, 'E%d'), strs, 'UniformOutput',false);
>> C = [C{:}]
ans =
    11    11
    25    28
     0     0
     0     0
     0     0
    16    16
    20    20
     4     4
     0     0
     7     7
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir Rody Oldenhuis ^_^